# algebraic reals: does z3 do rounding when pretty printing?

Tags: z3

If I issue:

```
(set-option :pp-decimal true)
(set-option :pp-decimal-precision 10)
```

Does Z3 do any rounding after the 10th digit of the real number? Or does it just chop the remaining digits without any rounding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Z3 4.0, an algebraic number `alpha` is represented using a univariate polynomial `p` and two binary rationals: `lower` and `upper`. A binary rational is a rational number of the form `a/2^k` where `a` is an integer and `k` a natural number. We have that `alpha` is the only root of `p` in the interval `(lower, upper)`. When the options

> (set-option :pp-decimal true)
>
> (set-option :pp-decimal-precision N)

are provided. First, I squeeze/refine the interval `(lower, upper)` until `upper - lower < 1/10^N`. Then, I peek the upper bound (which is a binary rational) and display it in decimal by chopping after the Nth digit. To be more precise, the refinement is actually performed until `upper - lower < 1/16^N`.

I realize this is not an ideal solution, but it is good enough for most purposes.